# how to describe a moq test in a nutshell in a conversation?

Tags: unit-testing, moq

What would be a natural way to describe the steps of a Moq test in a nutshell in a conversation?   I'm thinking:

1. Instantiate a Mock object for an interface
2. Set up dependencies for the Mock object
3. Use the Returns function to validate the expected result

Am I missing any steps or describing anything incorrectly or insufficiently?  I've used Moq on a previous project but I'm not a Moq or unit testing expert so looking for input from others who are more fluent in this domain.

Comment: What does "natural" mean?

Comment: Moq is used to fake external dependencies of the code under test (CUT). If your CUT e.g. writes to some file then it is considered to be external dependency and need to be mocked. The unit test will then test the method itself and not the writing to file system. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's give it a try:

1. Create the mock.
2. Set it up (if needed).
3. Inject the mock in the dependent object.
4. Call the method to test in the dependent object.
5. Verify that the proper methods of the mock have been called (and with the proper parameters, if any).

Comment: Let's say you were describing these steps in the context of an interview.  Should a mock *always* be created from an interface?  Is this a technical requirement or just a best practice?  It seems to be a fundamental concept of mocking, correct?   "Set it up (if needed)"   Can you please provide an example of a unit test scenario where the mock would *not* need to be set up?  I seem to remember doing Setup in all of the unit tests I've written.

Comment: First, a Moq can also be created from an abstract class, or even any non-sealed class (only the virtual methods will be mocked). And second, you can mock a class with a method that returns an integer. If you do not set it up, the method will return a default value (zero) that can be valid in some tests.

Comment: Thanks Carlos.  Given a scenario where a class has a related interface, the Mock should be created against the interface instead of the class, right?  Would you say that a Mock needs to be Setup in the vast majority of scenarios, particularly in the case of general enterprise applications?

Comment: Yes to both. I was going to edit my comment to say "you can mock an interface/class", but it seems that you cannot edit comments after five minutes. If you have an interface, mock against the interface. And indeed, you will need to set the mock up in the majority of scenarios. Do you really need this for an interview?

Comment: I implemented Moq unit tests on my last project but in a recent phone interview I realized that I was not describing it well so I'm trying to build out a good repeatable short answer.  It's a good exercise because it's helping me fill in a few small knowledge gaps along the way.

Answer (score 0):

That's the core of unit testing, being able to describe exactly what you're doing, and more importantly, what unit you're testing. Not too much, not too little, not testing the mock. Just testing a single *unit* of production code.

Defining "mocking" in a conversation requires us to know what unit testing is, like you said, *in a nutshell*. Right now I'd say unit testing is **putting the smallest possible portion of production code in a specific, realistic environment, to monitor and verify the intended results**. I just made that up so I'm sure you'll find a better definition somewhere else.

With that in mind, you could simply say **Mocking is the ability to control and setup exactly that given "*realistic and specific environment*"**.

Those two lines in bold is how I would define it to someone who knows what programming is ; if you're talking to a complete novice maybe we should have a different approach, but that's another question.

Also I feel like this question should be on programmers.stackexchange instead of SO. :P